# .NET multi threading await does not wait for async

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am facing problem with multi threading in .NET Framework 4.5 with await and async.

This is code.

```
List<Task<string>> t = new List<Task<string>>(); 
for (Row = 0; Row < lines.Count; Row++)
{        
  if (Row != 0 && lines[Row].Length >= CCColumnToken && lines[Row][CCColumnToken] != "")
  {
    t.Add(AccessPaymentVault(Row, credentials, cts.Token));
  }
}
string[] str_list = await Task.WhenAll(t.ToArray());
```

In below async function it seems `Tokenization.Retrive` is executed. But before it retrieves data, the whenAll finishes and the data is saved.

```
async Task<string> AccessPaymentVault(int row, Credentials credentials, CancellationToken ct){
    var data = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
      return Tokenization.Retrieve(credentials, lines[row][CCColumnToken]);
    }, ct);
    var returnData = Encryptor.Decrypt(data);
    if (returnData != null)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(returnData);
        lines[row][CCColumnNum] = (string)obj["cardNo"];
        lines[row][CCColumnExpiry] = (new DateTime(Int32.Parse((string)obj["expiryYYYY"]), Int32.Parse((string)obj["expiryMM"]), 1)).ToString("MM/yy");
    }
    return returnData;
}
```

Sometimes the code works well, but sometimes I think whenall doesn't work and some results(in random) are empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I very much doubt that `WhenAll` is broken. By "some results are empty" do you mean you get a null reference, or an empty string? Or do you mean that `lines` isn't populated? I suggest you work on coming up with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Is anything in the code that you have parallelized not thread-safe? Especially Tokenization.Retrieve. What is `lines`? Hopefully, it is a data-structure that is thread-safe.

Comment: Are you sure the return value gets populated eventually? The check for null there seems to indicate that the retrieve function may sometimes fail.

Comment: Throw an exception if the "returnData" variable is null right before returning and see what happen.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. No exception is thrown while running this code. As you may imagine, `Tokenization.Retrive` is connecting web service to retrieve credit card information. I think WhenAll does not wait for all of the Tasks and exit because the empty records are in random.